# Ec2 instance not connected via RDP

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, rdp

I am trying to connect my ec2 instance but it is stuck on initiating on rdp. Yesterday, I was able to connected but i saw black screen only. Today I am even not able to see that black screen .
In morning RDP was stuck on configuring session now it stuck on initiating after i close and then open all ports including RDP inboun

Comment: Please see the many, many StackOverflow questions around this topic. Main thing to check -- the IP address might have changed if you have Stopped & Started your instance. Check the EC2 console to confirm you are using the correct DNS Name / IP Address. Does it prompt you for your password, or if you change the password, do you get an error? This would indicate that it is connecting correctly and the problem is with Windows itself.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for you comments I searched first stackoverflow and tried suggested solutions but it did't work yes it seems to me also windows issue I think my machines storage is full that make this issue not sure. Right now I am creating image of my instance and launch a better configuration instance with that image.

Comment: There is no benefit in creating an AMI from the machine, since the new machine will have exactly the same content! You can always Stop the instance, change the instance type, then Start it again. You can also resize the disk, but that won't help because you need to login to expand the storage space.